# Can't login after editing xinitrc

Tags: arch-linux, x-server, xinit

I wanted to install **dwm** [according to this tutorial](http://tonylog.altervista.org/2008/12/15/how-to-install-configure-xorg-dwm-on-arch-linux). I've skipped the part about Xorg, bc I knew it have been already installed at the time. I started with step about installing dwm. The desktop stopped booting after editing xinitrc, as described in the tutorial above I've commented special lines and added `exec dwm` line in xinitrc. I didn't manage to login because it freezes when I type my password, but I can log in "terminal mode", I mean via pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. I've edited the xinitrc back using nano, i.e. uncommented lines and removed `exec dwm` line. My PC still freezes at logging stage.

My **xinitrc** is looking like this right now:

```
#!/bin/sh

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then



xrdb -merge $sysresources

fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then



xrdb -merge "$userresources"

fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
  [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi

twm &
xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 &
xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 &
xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 &
exec xterm -geometry 80x66+0+0 -name login
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is immediately obvious to me in this file. But here's a generic debugging tip which should lead you to the problem.

Just below the `#!/bin/sh` shebang line, add the following lines:

```
exec >~/"xinitrc-$DISPLAY.log" 2>&1
set -x
```

`set -x` turns on the shell's trace mode, so every command will be printed just before it's executed. The `exec` line redirects the log to a file in your home directory (adjust as desired).

Either you'll see the file grow very fast if there's an infinite loop somewhere, or it'll stop logging at the problematic command.

Comment: I don't see any logs in home directory. Also, will they be there if I'm using xinitrc from "/etc/X11/xinit/" not from "~/"?

Comment: @pushandpop No matter, you should see logs, as long as you're starting X with `startx` or `xinit` (if you use a display manager, `xinitrc` isn't executed, unless Arch has set up the X session start scripts to execute it from `Xsession`).